# Loop through dropdown browsermenu with VBA

Tags: html, vba, object, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I need to loop through a dropdown list of a specific website and download the latest file for each entry. I managed to open the website and click the "submit" button, but I can´t find a solution to loop through all the dropdown entries.

```
Dim reportnr As String
Dim internetadress As String
Dim btn As Object
Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

reportnr = 10
                         
                                                      
                            
 internetadress = adress & reportnr
    
                    Set IE = CreateObject('InternetExplorer.Application')
                            IE.Visible = True
                            IE.navigate internetadress
                            Do While IE.Busy
                            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)
                            Loop
 

While IE.Busy
DoEvents
Wend

    For Each btn In IE.document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")

        If btn.name = "submit" Then
            btn.Click
        End If

    Next btn
```

The code on the website regarding the dropdown below.

[image]

I tried several approchoaches, but I´ll get error or just nothing happens. Last thing I tried is this :

```
Option Explicit
'VBE > Tools > References:
' Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub SelectQuantity()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, numberOfOptions As Long, i As Long

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.amazon.com/belif-True-Cream-Aqua-Korean/dp/B00H4GOAZO/ref=pd_cart_crc_cko_cp_2_2/139-8277217-3794320?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B00H4GOAZO&pd_rd_r=e154e278-8a11-4ab0-8173-5d0dbaff1938&pd_rd_w=Hm8FW&pd_rd_wg=Hpv4X&pf_rd_p=eff166ab-25d2-4f2c-a51d-0a0e86061f9d&pf_rd_r=EVT26E6K7CV8T1QMTY7H&psc=1&refRID=EVT26E6K7CV8T1QMTY7H"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            numberOfOptions = .querySelectorAll("#quantity option").Length 'gather option tag element children of parent select element with id quantity
            For i = 1 To numberOfOptions
                .querySelector("#quantity [value='" & i & "']").Selected = True
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = i
            Next
            Stop
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Source: [VBA loop through dropdown elements from web page and download to excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998359/vba-loop-through-dropdown-elements-from-web-page-and-download-to-excel-sheet)

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: We can't see the relevant html for the select element. Also, use snippet tool via [edit] to insert html rather than post images. Additionally, your code will fail as you loop to .Length instead of .Length -1. Embarrassing is that the fault is mine in the original code. I have edited that part of the quoted link to be correct. Apologies.

Comment: Is the website internal? If not, you can provide the link of the website so that we can have a test and see how to help. If you can't provide the link, please provide the detailed html code of the dropdown list instead of a picture.

Comment: Okay, I´m sorry I will do this next time. Thanks for your help in advance. The link to the website is the following: https://www.theice.com/marketdata/reports/10. We need to obtain the files in the dropdown menu on daily basis.

Answer (score 0):

From the website you provide, you can try the following code to loop through the dropdown list to choose the option you want:

```
Set lists = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("active-result")  'get all the options li elements

For Each liElement In lists
    If liElement.innerText = "something" Then
         liElement.setAttribute "class", "active-result result-selected"
    End If
Next liElement
```

I find that the chosen option has different class which is `active-result result-selected`, so I think maybe you can change the class to select the option.